# SpringBoot model attributes not available after post request

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to return some values to my webapp after a form is submitted via a post request.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class testController {

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/testPage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String downloadFile(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("file") File file) {
data = file.generateData; //This method returns a string
model.addAttribute("output", fileOutput);
return "testPage";
```

**HTML**
Using ThymeLeaf

```
<p th:text="${output}"></p>
```

The

tag does not contain the expected data so it is empty.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the method with @ResponseBody is return the String "testPage"
if your page name is testPage,then remove the annotation @ResponseBody

Comment: Removing @ResponseBody is giving me the following:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`

Comment: According to the code I see, it should not cause this problem, it is estimated that your code is not written completely. The reason for this exception is that the output of the stream is called repeatedly